# Animating from top and not center of intrinsic size

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, intrinsic-content-size

I'm trying to get my views to animate from top to bottom. Currently, when changing the text of my label, between nil and some "error message", the labels are animated from the center of its intrinsic size, but I want the regular "label" to be "static" and only animate the errorlabel. Basically the error label should be located directly below the regular label and the errorlabel should be expanded according to its (intrinsic)height. This is essentially for a checkbox. I want to show the error message when the user hasn't checked the checkbox yet, but are trying to proceed further. The code is just a basic implementation that explains the problem. I've tried adjusting anchorPoint and contentMode for the containerview but those doesn't seem to work the way I thought. Sorry if the indentation is weird

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let container = UIView()
    let errorLabel = UILabel()


    var bottomLabel: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(container)
        container.contentMode = .top
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        container.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Very long text that i would like to show to full extent and eventually add an error message to. It'll work on multiple rows obviously"
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        container.contentMode = .top
        container.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: container.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        container.addSubview(errorLabel)
        errorLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(300), for: .vertical)
        errorLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        errorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        errorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        errorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        bottomLabel = errorLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: container.bottomAnchor)
        bottomLabel.isActive = false

        errorLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        container.backgroundColor = .green
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTap))
        container.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func onTap() {

        self.container.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            let active = !self.bottomLabel.isActive
            self.bottomLabel.isActive = active
            self.errorLabel.text = active ? "A veru very veru very veru very veru very veru very veru very veru very veru very long Error message" : nil


            self.container.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want your error message label to "slide down" into view? Or do you want the animation to appear as if the error label is already there, but is being "revealed" by a "cover" sliding down?

Comment: I think it's the second option that you're talking about that I'm after. I want the errorlabels top pinned to the bottom of the label (as is right now), and expand its intrinsic height and being "revealed" as you say. Think of it as a "form" that I want to display an error message if the input is improperly formed. It could also be say, an input-view where I want to display an error below if the input is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since it's a control that I wanted to create (checkbox) in this case with an error message, I manipulated the frames directly, based on the bounds. So to get it to work properly, I used a combination of overriding intrinsicContentSize and layoutSubviews and some minor extra stuff. The class contains a bit more than provided, but the provided code should hopefully explain the approach I went with.

```
open class Checkbox: UIView {



let imageView = UIImageView()
let textView = ThemeableTapLabel()
private let errorLabel = UILabel()
var errorVisible: Bool = false
let checkboxPad: CGFloat = 8

override open var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        // fixes layout when bounds change
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}


open var errorMessage: String? {
    didSet {
        self.errorVisible = self.errorMessage != nil
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            if self.errorMessage != nil {
                self.errorLabel.text = self.errorMessage
            }
            self.setNeedsLayout()
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { success in

            if self.errorMessage == nil {
                self.errorLabel.text = nil
            }
        })
    }
}


func checkboxSize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: imageView.image?.size.width ?? 0, height: imageView.image?.size.height ?? 0)
}


override open func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    frame = bounds
    let imageFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: checkboxSize().width, height: checkboxSize().height)
    imageView.frame = imageFrame

    let textRect = textView.textRect(forBounds: CGRect(x: (imageFrame.width + checkboxPad), y: 0, width: bounds.width - (imageFrame.width + checkboxPad), height: 10000), limitedToNumberOfLines: textView.numberOfLines)
    textView.frame = textRect


    let largestHeight = max(checkboxSize().height, textRect.height)
    let rect = errorLabel.textRect(forBounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 10000), limitedToNumberOfLines: errorLabel.numberOfLines)
    //po bourect = rect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: imageFrame.maxY)
    let errorHeight = errorVisible ? rect.height : 0
    errorLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: largestHeight, width: bounds.width, height: errorHeight)

}

override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    get {

        let textRect = textView.textRect(forBounds: CGRect(x: (checkboxSize().width + checkboxPad), y: 0, width: bounds.width - (checkboxSize().width + checkboxPad), height: 10000), limitedToNumberOfLines: textView.numberOfLines)

        let rect = errorLabel.textRect(forBounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 10000), limitedToNumberOfLines: errorLabel.numberOfLines)
        let errorHeight = errorVisible ? rect.height : 0
        let largestHeight = max(checkboxSize().height, textRect.height)
        return CGSize(width: checkboxSize().width + 200, height: largestHeight + errorHeight)
    }
}


public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {

//...
    addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addSubview(textView)
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.numberOfLines = 0
    contentMode = .top

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(checkboxTap(sender:)))
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    addSubview(errorLabel)
    errorLabel.contentMode = .top
    errorLabel.textColor = .red
    errorLabel.numberOfLines = 0

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found it a bit difficult to get dynamic multiline labels to "animate" in the way I want - particularly when I want to "hide" the label.

One approach: Create 2 "error" labels, with one overlaid on top of the other. Use the "hidden" label to control the constraints on the container view. When animating the change, the container view's bounds will effectively "reveal" and "conceal" (show/hide) the "visible" label.

Here is an example, that you can run directly in a Playground page:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class RevealViewController: UIViewController {

    let container = UIView()
    let staticLabel = UILabel()
    let hiddenErrorLabel = UILabel()
    let visibleErrorLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // colors, just so we can see the bounds of the labels
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        container.backgroundColor = .green
        staticLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        visibleErrorLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan

        // we don't want to see this label, so set its alpha to zero
        hiddenErrorLabel.alpha = 0.0

        // we want the Error Label to be "revealed" - so when it is has text it is initially "covered"
        container.clipsToBounds = true

        // all labels may be multiple lines
        staticLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        hiddenErrorLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        visibleErrorLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        // initial text in the "static" label
        staticLabel.text = "Very long text that i would like to show to full extent and eventually add an error message to. It'll work on multiple rows obviously"

        // add the container view to the VC's view
        // pin it to the sides, and 100-pts from the top
        // NO bottom constraint
        view.addSubview(container)
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0).isActive = true
        container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // add the static label to the container
        // pin it to the top and sides
        // NO bottom constraint
        container.addSubview(staticLabel)
        staticLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        staticLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive = true
        staticLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        staticLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // add the "hidden" error label to the container
        // pin it to the sides, and  pin its top to the bottom of the static label
        // NO bottom constraint
        container.addSubview(hiddenErrorLabel)
        hiddenErrorLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hiddenErrorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staticLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        hiddenErrorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        hiddenErrorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // add the "visible" error label to the container
        // pin its top, leading and trailing constraints to the hidden label
        container.addSubview(visibleErrorLabel)
        visibleErrorLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        visibleErrorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenErrorLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
        visibleErrorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenErrorLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        visibleErrorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hiddenErrorLabel.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // pin the bottom of the hidden label ot the bottom of the container
        // now, when we change the text of the hidden label, it will
        // "push down / pull up" the bottom of the container view
        hiddenErrorLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        // add a tap gesture
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTap))
        container.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    }

    var myActive = false

    @objc func onTap() {

        let errorText = "A veru very veru very veru very veru very veru very veru very veru very veru very long Error message"

        self.myActive = !self.myActive

        if self.myActive {

            // we want to SHOW the error message

            // set the error message in the VISIBLE error label
            self.visibleErrorLabel.text = errorText

            // "animate" it, with duration of 0.0 - so it is filled instantly
            // it will extend below the bottom of the container view, but won't be
            // visible yet because we set .clipsToBounds = true on the container
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {

            }, completion: {
                _ in

                // now, set the error message in the HIDDEN error label
                self.hiddenErrorLabel.text = errorText

                // the hidden label will now "push down" the bottom of the container view
                // so we can animate the "reveal"
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                })

            })

        } else {

            // we want to HIDE the error message

            // clear the text from the HIDDEN error label
            self.hiddenErrorLabel.text = ""

            // the hidden label will now "pull up" the bottom of the container view
            // so we can animate the "conceal"
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: {
                _ in

                // after its hidden, clear the text of the VISIBLE error label
                self.visibleErrorLabel.text = ""

            })

        }

    }

}

let vc = RevealViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tested a playground before and don't really know how it works. I did however, test your approach but didn't get it to work properly. It did do a "foldout" animation as I hoped, but the (container)frame still made a jump when animating, which made it layout my view over content that was above my container view. It also felt wrong to have two views when there should only be the need for one. I came up with a different solution though